# Youtube HTML5 3D Upload issues

Tags: 3d, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video, stereo-3d

I have a finished a sample video in Cyberlink PowerDirector 11 using stereoscopic 3D.  I rendered the video in separate runs as both an MPEG4 AVC and H.264 AVC formats at 1920x1080 resolution using SBS Half Width "squished" L/R.

I have an Asus 3D Monitor and am using the Nvidia 3D Vision2 kit.  Once the video was rendered, I popped it into the Nvidia 3D video player and it worked perfectly, overlaying both the L/R eye videos.

So I figured it would be a simple process to upload the video to Youtube and be able to view them in 3D with my Nvidia glasses using Youtube HTML5 3D with the newest version of Firefox.  I have had no problem viewing other 3D videos doing this.

The problem is when I view the video in FF on YT, I still see the SBS images separated instead of overlayed.  I did some research and it seemed like I needed to use the WebM (VP8/Vorbis) instead of an mp4 or m2ts AVC file for an HTML5 video.

So after playing with a few converters I finally managed to convert both the A&V to WebM.  I popped the new video back into the 3D player and it worked fine again.  After re-uploading to YT, I STILL only see the separate images instead of them being mashed together.  I have yt3d:enable=true and yt3d:aspect=16:9 in the tags.

I also noticed when I look at Stats for nerds on a HTML5 3D I see "mime type=video/webm; codecs=vp8.0,vorbis" but my video says "video/mp4;codes=avc1,mp4a".

Here is the YT video in question:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pL4uOMOkOic&feature=html5_3d

Here is the actual WebM file I uploaded to MF (recoded at a low bitrate, only 50 MB):
http://www.mediafire.com/download/c2aola7tgkst172/SC_Demo01.webm

---

I was wondering if anyone could DL the video and see if it works in their Nvidia 3D video player and if they have any success uploading it properly to YT as an HTML5 3D.

At this point I've spent several hours re-encoding and uploading and I'm fed up with trying anymore.  I kind of want to know if this is a YT bug and not something I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your youtube video seems to be displaying correctly with my nvidia 3d vision system. I recently uploaded a 3D video that only appeared side-by-side right after I uploaded it, but then was correct 3D the next day. Perhaps you just need to wait for youtube eventually sprinkle some secret sauce that makes it work correctly. Your video seems to have that sauce now.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube broke 3D on html5. For viewing all 3D videos on youtube you will need to downgrade to Firefox 12